# communicating with multiple slave (Modbus protocol based)

Tags: c#, .net, modbus

I am developing an application in which Lets says 50-60 Modbus supporting devices (Slaves) are connected to a Com Port which are communicating with my application in request response mechanism.

I want after every 15 min. request should be sent to every meter and response to be received from meter one by one.
communicating with multiple slave (Modbus protocol based)

For this i am making the use of System.Timers.timer to call the method lets say ReadAllSlave() after every 15 min. 
In ReadAllSlave() i have used For loop to send the request and to receive response and using thread.sleep to maintain the delay..! but it seems that its not working and loop is executing in damn wired way.

```
private void StartPoll()
   {
      double txtSampleRate = 15 * 60 * 1000;
      timer.Interval = txtSampleRate;
      timer.AutoReset = true;
      timer.Start();
   }

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
 for(int index = 0; index<meterCount; Index++)
 {
       //Sending request to connected meter..  
       mb.SendFc3(m_slaveID[0], m_startRegAdd[0], m_noOfReg[0], ref value_meter);
       if (mb.modbusStatus == "Read successful")
           {

                   //Some code for writing the values in SQL Express database
           }

       //Wait for some time so that will not get timeout error for the next 
       //request..
       Thread.Sleep(10000);

  }
}
```

Can any one please suggest me the best approach to implement the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the real problem? You dont get any  values after the first iteration? If i read your intention correct, you try to communicate 50 meters on a slow 9600 baud speed line for every fifteen second. Not sure if its even possible.

Comment: The code of your send receive loop or at least a cut down version of it would help. Sounds like you are trying to do asynchronous comms synchronously to me.

Comment: My bad, you wrote minutes. Code sample would help, indeed.

Comment: @Jonas i want to communicate with all the slaves after every 15 min. There is no problem with request or response from the slave .. Its working very fine if i remove the for loop and write the same iteration for every slave.. So my problem me what approach should i follow Threading or something else like that...!!

Comment: I'm not sure if you truncated your code too much though. But based on your provided code, I find Alexandres answer useful. Though, I can see that you just have to provide m_slaveID[index] instead of m_slaveID[0]. If I understand your framework for reading mbus-datagrams right, the other to parameters point to the datarecords being readed (and should be zero, if that is what work for you in single test).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is a trivial one... You're always interrogating the same slave !
"index" is never used in your code...

What about something like this :

```
mb.SendFc3(m_slaveID[index], m_startRegAdd[index], m_noOfReg[index], ref value_meter);
```